# Web pages take forever to load when using burp suite

Tags: burp, foxyproxy

I'm new to burp suite and I'm getting lot of errors with it, one of the errors are this. When I'm trying to access web pages (ex:- google.com, hackerone etc.) it just never load in the web page( Intercept is off) and I'm using chrome. Please help me with this matter.

OS : Windows

Proxy : FoxyProxy(127.0.0.1 : 8080)

note : intercept is off when I'm browsing

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't understand your problem but here are some points to keep in note while using Burpsuite.

1. Make sure CA Certificate is properly installed in browser
2. Add your target host to scope. For example if you are testing on xyz.com then add this host to scope so even if intercept in ON other host's requests will be ignored by interceptor.
3. Slow loading is might be your internet issue
4. Make sure your 8080 port is not blocked by any other service.
5. Try changing your browser incase of getting errors
6. Burpsuite will not work while having VPN or other proxy is ON

Answer (score 0):

if you have that issue while "Intercept is off" then I had the same issue. So what helped me was to open one more browser window, using the top "Open browser" button

Answer (score 0):

change the **proxy setting to auto** while **turning off the intercept** in order to send the packets to router